# select from parent table having condition in child table

Tags: sql, select

I have parent table as

```
pID    Name
1      AAA
2      BBB
3      CCC
```

and a child table as

```
cID    pID         Name
1      1           XXX
2      1           YYY
3      2           XXX
4      2           YYY
5      2           ZZZ
6      3           YYY
7      3           ZZZ
```

now i need to select the parent rows that have at least 2 child rows one of them have the value YYY and the other ZZZ, which should be pID 2 & 3.

is this possible?

thanks in advance everyone

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: thanks for the edit GMB

Comment: SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select p.pid,p.name from c join p on p.pid=c.pid
where c.name in ('YYY','ZZZ')
group by p.pid,p.name
having count(distinct c.name)=2
```